# DataGrid Row & Cell Style in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to set a DataGrid style within `app.xaml`. I've tried adding a style in however I am unsure of the semantics required to add a Cell and Row style.

This is what I have tried so far;

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid" x:Name="noighlightRowDataGrid">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="Blue" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

I can see that dropping the `DataGrid.CellStyle` into the DataGrid style isn't going to work but like I said I am unsure on how to create the style properly.

Comment: Well if you would like your style to be used automatically you have to remove the X:Name

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil I don't want it to be applied automatically, only to those where I specify the style to be this.

Comment: The you have to specify a key for your new created style x:Key="xxxx"

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the row and cell styles independently.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hi hank, I'm defining this in my app.xaml so I would like to include the styles within the DataGrid style if at all possible.

Comment: <DataGrid.RowStyle = What to get it from app.xaml />